# Timing functions on the MSP430FR6989 in C

Tags: c, msp430

For a project I want to time how long a function takes. For this, I was thinking of using TimerA TA0 and a capture. However, after looking through the documentation, I was wondering if it is possible to capture the timer using an internal "message". In the datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr6989.pdf page 87, table at the bottom of the page)  it is not really clear to me how to do this. It states the Port pins which can be used, but I am (obviously) not interested in that. 
I was thus thinking if I was able to write to the TAxIV regitser, to just set the interrupt flag myself, but I'm absolutely not sure if it would work (I don't really think so, but I don't know why), I could use that to capture the timer.

I also already looked at the example code, but there they use ACLK to as an input signal. So that is not of much use either.

With kind regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the Timer_A block diagram (figure 25-1) in the User's Guide, the capture signal must come from one of the four capture inputs.

The last two inputs are always connected to GND and V<sub>CC</sub>, so you can trigger the capture manually by switching between these two inputs (see section 25.2.4.1.1).

Comment: So I guess the code would then look something like this (correct me if I am wrong)?

for initialisations:

TA0CCTL1 = CM_3 | CCIS_1 | SCS | CAP; // no interrupt like in the example, see datasheet
TA0CTL = TASSEL__SMCLK | MC__CONTINUOUS; // setting the timer up with the SMCLK
and for usage, meaning capturing the timer:

TA0CCTL1 ^= CCIS0 // TA0CCR1 = TA0R, toggling the CCIS0 bit to switch between Vcc and GND
and then just reading the capture register out?

Comment: Yes. But why no interrupt?

Comment: That was what the datasheet gave. I found it kinda strange. 
So with interrupt then?

Comment: Well, do you want to handle it with an interrupt, or with polling?

Comment: Well, if I toggle the bit, the new value will be put inside the capture  register anyway. I can just read out that buffer whenever I want no (as long as I don't overwrite it)? There is no need to interrupt (or even poll) I guess? 
or is the interrupt also used for putting the timer value in the capture register?

Comment: Yes, in this case, you know when the capture has happened.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (all thanks go to CL. ,see above, who gave the answer):

for initialisations:

```
TA0CCTL1 = CM_3 | CCIS_1 | SCS | CAP; // could put in interrupt here
TA0CTL = TASSEL__SMCLK | MC__CONTINUOUS; // setting the timer up with the SMCLK
```

and for usage, meaning capturing the timer:

```
TA0CCTL1 ^= CCIS0 // TA0CCR1 = TA0R, toggling the CCIS0 bit to switch between Vcc and GND
```

and then just reading the capture register out.

This answer is here to make it easier to read, for the full answer see my conversation with CL. above, whom gave me the answer.